# Взаимодействие с сетевой картой в Linux Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Всем привет. Необходимо написать приложение для взаимодействия с сетевой картой, а именно определять какие порты заняты, объем проходящих пакетов (в дальнейшем смотреть что это за пакеты). Подскажите может есть статьи или библиотеки для этого или возможно силами Qt это реализовать. Разработка под linux в Qt.

Comment: А Вы точно уверены, что Вам нужно именно с сетевой картой взаимодействовать? pcap похоже решит большинство проблем

Comment: какие порты заняты можно посмотреть в `/proc/net/{tcp,udp}`... какие «открыты» — очень геморройно определить, в общем случае, пожалуй, даже невозможно... а для сниффинга только средствами Кьюта не обойтись точно — нужно API ОС (если кратко, то для этого есть специальное семейство сокетов), или из библиотек — `libpcap`, конечно...

Comment: изучаю содержимое файла /proc/net/tcp и что тут порты ???

Comment: @Samsongoot, то что в колонках {local,rem}_address после двоеточеей.. ЗЫ: используй упоминание через собаку в комментариях, если ожидаешь ответа...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если посмотреть `cat /proc/net/tcp`, то второй столбец local_address это адрес и порт открытого соединения.

017AA8C0:DA6A это 192.168.122.1:55914

В /proc/net/netstat есть строчка с InOctets OutOctets - объем принятых и переданных данных

```
IpExt: InNoRoutes InTruncatedPkts InMcastPkts OutMcastPkts InBcastPkts OutBcastPkts InOctets OutOctets InMcastOctets OutMcastOctets InBcastOctets OutBcastOctets InCsumErrors InNoECTPkts InECT1Pkts InECT0Pkts InCEPkts ReasmOverlaps
IpExt: 29         0               138065      42354        5276        64           3793059629 4695476698 54492046   13672637        825945  33693 0 4846499 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: в /proc/net/tcp так же можно найти номер inode, по которому можно, просмотрев каталоги процессов в том же /proc, определить какой процесс работает с портом.
Третья колонка (st) - состояние сокета, 0A - значит открыт в ожидании соединения (listen)